# Login to alpine based cachet container using SSH

Tags: docker, ssh, containers, alpine-linux, sshd

I am working on implementing [cachet](https://github.com/CachetHQ/Docker) status page service and have a requirement to login to the cachet container using SSH.

Cachet uses nginx:1.17.8-alpine as base image and I added the below section to the existing [Dockerfile](https://github.com/CachetHQ/Docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) to install and setup SSH. I replaced `CMD ["/sbin/entrypoint.sh"]` to `ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/entrypoint.sh"]` to accomadate the CMD command for starting sshd.

```
RUN apk --update add --no-cache openrc openssh \
  && sed -i s/#PermitRootLogin.*/PermitRootLogin\ yes/ /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
  && echo "root:root" | chpasswd \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
  && sed -ie 's/#Port 22/Port 22/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
  && sed -ri 's/#HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_key/HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_key/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
  && sed -ir 's/#HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_rsa_key/HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_rsa_key/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
  && sed -ir 's/#HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_dsa_key/HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_dsa_key/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
  && sed -ir 's/#HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_ecdsa_key/HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_ecdsa_key/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
  && sed -ir 's/#HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_ed25519_key/HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_ed25519_key/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
  && /usr/bin/ssh-keygen -A \
  && ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f  /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
RUN rc-update add sshd
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D"]
EXPOSE 22
```

Also added 22 to the ports section in the [docker compose file](https://github.com/CachetHQ/Docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) as below:

```
  cachet:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - cachet_ver=2.4
    ports:
      - 80:8000
      - 22
```

After docker-compose build and up, I checked the docker info and am able to see a port being assigned to 22 as below

```
  "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "e17c53db8acf117d93dcc36d9e35f317433e877ea3ac3962f0d28c3403a9cdb0",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "22/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "32955"
                    }
                ],
                "80/tcp": null,
                "8000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
```

The IP address of the container from docker inspect is as below:

```
    "Networks": {
        "cachet-docker_default": {
            "IPAMConfig": null,
            "Links": [
                "cachet-docker_postgres_1:cachet-docker_postgres_1",
                "cachet-docker_postgres_1:postgres",
                "cachet-docker_postgres_1:postgres_1"
            ],
            "Aliases": [
                "e8be9717eb77",
                "cachet"
            ],
            "NetworkID": "44521f9cd8b2d17c46a80487ad20e8b27e377c99193ef21d24c0d1c2f70ff451",
            "EndpointID": "e735db62d60647687f066bb973243d9ddb4ba20dfd097344f8a487ece37256b5",
            "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
            "IPAddress": "172.18.0.3",
```

But when I try to SSH into the container I get the below error

```
cachet-docker$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                 NAMES
e8be9717eb77        cachet-docker_cachet   "/sbin/entrypoint.sh…"   21 hours ago        Up 21 hours         80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32955->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->8000/tcp   cachet-docker_cachet_1
c8000b2b64ec        postgres:12-alpine     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   21 hours ago        Up 21 hours         5432/tcp                                              cachet-docker_postgres_1
cachet-docker$ ssh root@172.18.0.3 -p 32955
ssh: connect to host 172.18.0.3 port 32955: Operation timed out
cachet-docker$ ssh root@localhost -p 32955
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
cachet-docker$ ssh root@localhost 
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
cachet-docker$ ssh root@172.18.0.3
ssh: connect to host 172.18.0.3 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Before this I tried generating ssh keys and then add config to Dockerfile for copying the public key into the container by creating a ~/.ssh folder and authorized_key file then copying the public key into the file and assigning proper file permissions., But that too did not work and gave me the same error as above.
Would you pleas help me understand where I am going wrong?

Comment: can you try `nmap -p 32955 172.18.0.3` and `ssh root@172.18.0.3 -p 32955 -v` and post the output ?